# How to create a custom asynchronous validator in express-validator?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, asynchronous

I want to create a custom validator to to check duplicate email in the database. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), you just add in an object that defines each validator you want to use.

```
app.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: {
    isArray: function(value) {
        return Array.isArray(value);
    },
    gte: function(param, num) {
        return param >= num;
    }
 }
}));
```

It looks like the docs do not cover asynchronous stuff (e.g. checking a db), but there was a pull request several years ago that added the ability to [return a Promise](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator/pull/164) from a custom validator.

Comment: I know how to add simple validation like this. I am asking how to write asynchronous validator

Comment: That's why I linked the pull request, you have to return a Promise.